# Java selecting and summing from sqlite database

Tags: java, database, sqlite

So..
i can select from db and get all data, for now it looks like this:

```
value   date                    comment
```

---

```
1123.0  2011/05/31 03:05        asdsad
123.0   2011/05/30 02:41        qw
10.0    2011/05/30 02:35        alga
```

i store date as text.
i dont know how to make query, to sum all values, if date are the same.

Comment: Why do you store date as text? Doesn't sqlite support date fields? Offer date functions? In most cases it is foolish to build such functionality yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select sum(value), date from yourtable group by date

Comment: SELECT sum(inVALUE) as inSUM, substr(inDATE, 0, 10) as inDATE from inTABLE group by inDATE order by inDATE DESC;"